# Scroll one cell at a time in collection View

Tags: ios, objective-c

Using the `willDisplayCell` method I got the index of the last visible cell:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {       
   indexVisibleCell = [indexPath indexAtPosition:[indexPath length] - 1];
}
```

where `indexVisibleCell` is an `NSUInteger` that is declared in the class' interface. My problem is that I want to shift only one cell when user taps on the right or left button. I have applied this code for that purpose:

```
- (IBAction)rightButton:(id)sender {
    NSUInteger indexOfScrolledCell;
    indexOfScrolledCell = indexVisibleCell;

  if (indexVisibleCell < 9) {            
        NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexOfScrolledCell+1 inSection:0];

        [self.obj_CollectionView1 scrollToItemAtIndexPath:path atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionLeft animated:YES];            
    }     
}
```

as I show 3 cells at a time. By using that rightButton action method it shifts 3 cells at a time, not one. Please help me figure out how to scroll one cell at time.

Comment: set `pagingEnabled` to `YES` for `UICollectionView`. Either in IB or in Code.

Comment: with paging enabled, his collection view (with 3 cells shown at a time) will scroll every 3 cells, which is not his desired 1 cell at a time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [visibleCells](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/visibleCells) to get your visible Cells, get the leftmost Cell index to figure out the next index, then scroll to that Cell on the left (similar logic to your code).
`willDisplayCell` is not reliable since it is called both times when you scroll left/right, and you're thinking that index is the left/right most is not correct.

Edit:
Or you need to compare the index in `willDisplayCell` correctly, to get the correct left/right most index, based on your logic.

Answer (score 8):

Try using `UICollectionView` with paging enabled. Use following code, hopefully it works out for you.

```
[yourCollectionView setPagingEnabled:YES];
```

Comment: with paging enabled, his collection view (with 3 cells shown at a time) will scroll every 3 cells, which is not his desired 1 cell at a time

Answer (score 1):

For right button you can use following

```
[self.obj_CollectionView1 scrollToItemAtIndexPath:path atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionRight animated:YES];
```

and for left button following

```
[self.obj_CollectionView1 scrollToItemAtIndexPath:path atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionLeft animated:YES];
```

I am changing `UICollectionViewScrollPosition` so that when you scroll to right new item shows up on right side of collection view and when you scroll to left new item shows on left side of collection view.